# How do you fix User Profile Service after the wizard

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I am trying to get the User Profile sync to start on my SharePoint 2013 server.

Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

I did start off when we first got the server with the Wizard which I now know is a big no.

I was reading a blog that there was a fix to this but the link was dead and I have not been able to find another fix.

Anyone else have a fix or how to reconfigure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do is to delete what you have and to start again. Follow the instructions in http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx (yes, I know it says 2010, but it's the same for 2013) to get it all up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

When going in the `Central Administration` page, than `Application Management`->`Manage service applications`->`User Profile Service Application` and click on `Configure Synchronization Connections` in `Synchronization` section, You can find that the connection was missing.

I found an article related to the problem:

[Synchronization Connection missing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80fb3c8f-a91a-461e-ad8b-52fc4a771118/synchronization-connection-missing)

**The Answer:**

Please do not recreate the connection. Please check if `Forefront Identity Manager Service` and `FIM Sync service are running` (in services.msc console) - probably they are stopped, that's why your synchronization connection isn't visible.

Please also check if `User Profile Service` and `User Profile Synchronization service is running`.

We had to simply start back the stopped services (FIM and FIM Sync) and all seems to work fine now.

1. Start services.msc
2. Find the services listed in the link's answer above, and start those that are stopped

Hope that helps anyone else possibly facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The services were disabled. Looks like I may as well start from scratch again.

Comment: If my answer helps you than please mark the answer as correct . So others can get help from it.

Comment: If the services are disabled you should NOT start them manually. The right next step is to start over with Spence's article mentioned in Andy's answer.